# ` docker-compose up ` invalid service name '.....' - only [a-zA-Z0-9\._\-] characters are allowed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I have a local docker image which has name `img_test`. My `docker-compose.yml` file is:

```
version: '2'

services:

   img_test:
      image: img_test:latest
      ports:
         - "8080:80"

   mysql:
      image: mysql:latest
      ports:
         - "3636:3036"

   nvidia/cuda:
      image: nvidia/cuda:latest
      runtime: nvidia
      command: nvidia-smi

networks:
   appnet:
      external: true
```

I also have `Dockerfile` . When I run the command `docker-compose up` It throws this error.

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Invalid service name 'img_test' - only [a-zA-Z0-9\._\-] characters are allowed
```

I gave another names such as `img/test`, `imgtest` but they did not work.

I also tried build the `Dockerfile` in `docker-compose.yml` file by this command.

```
version: '2'

services:

   app:
      build: .
```

It gives same error for `app`.

What is the solution? I am new on `Docker`. I tested my image and it is working correctly. I dont want to push my image to Dockerhub. Is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: The error in the second case must be different. Can you check?

Comment: ` ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Invalid service name 'app' - only [a-zA-Z0-9\._\-] characters are allowed ` The same error again.

Comment: I see, this is likely a bug. Docker and docker-compose versions?

Comment: Docker version 1.12.6-cs13, build 0ee24d4, 
docker-compose version 1.8.0, build unknown

Comment: I have installed docker-compose by using "apt install docker-compose". Maybe I should try to install by another way.

Comment: Oh yes, it is typical to get old versions using apt. Try manually downloading.

Comment: I reinstalled it manually and it is fixed. Thank you :)

Comment: I'm glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a relatively old version of docker-compose. They had this bug in the past. Try upgrading.

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4754